# How to change horizontal menu to vertical menu on mobile with css

Tags: html, css

I need to design a responsive template for my website publishing class.  I already know a bit of jquery, so I decided to convert my horizontal navigation menu in the desktop version to a vertical menu in the mobile version.  Basically, instead of displaying all of the navigation list items, which breaks at a certain width, I want the menu to appear when you click on the "Navigation" text.  I've gotten the menu to hide on mobile until you click the nav text and the list displays when it's told to.  My problem is that when the actual menu appears, it expands the height of the nav element which is the parent of the ul.  How can I fix my code so that the height of the nav element is unchanged and the list appears outside of the nav element directly below the Navigation text?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKQU.jpg

The css:

```
#navTrigger {
    display: none;
}
nav {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: url(../images/wood_dark.png);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 2px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-bottom-color: #888;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 960px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-left: 73px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #888888;
    border-left: 1px solid #444444;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width:790px){
    #navTrigger {
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 124px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        float: none;
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<nav>
      <span id="navTrigger">Navigation</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html" title="Our Products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html" title="Our Services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" title="About Us">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html" title="Help and Support">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: you could try `display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;height:100px;        border: solid 1px black;;` for `ul li a` in `@media only screen and (max-width:790px)` part

Answer (score 0):

"`@media only screen and...`" doesn't always work...

Try, `@media(max-width: 790px)`